# What is the difference between a strain wave gearing and a Harmonic drive?

Tags: gears

I see there are two different Wikipedia pages for [strain wave gearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_wave_gearing) and [Harmonic drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_drive). To my knowledge they are the same. Harmonic Drive is the trademarked name of strain wave gearing by United Shoe Machinery Corp. Am I doing any mistakes here or what?

Comment: I think you might want to select a less abusive and hostile username

Comment: argh :-(   it'll get you in trouble in the USA -- check the Urban Dictionary.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could remove these comments as they are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the opening line of your [linked wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_drive)

> "A harmonic gear is a strain wave gear"...

The first line is quite explicit in saying that they are the same thing.  The second line says:

> *Harmonic Drive* is trademarked by the Harmonic Drive company.

I don't really see any reason to assume they are not the same thing.  "Harmonic Drive" is the brand name.

Comment: Then why there are two different wikipedia entries? shouldn't they just be merged?

Comment: Probably; but I don't know enough about Wikipedia policy to know where they stand on redundancies.  The paragraphs on "History" and "Mechanics" both start the exact same on the two articles.  I'm pretty confident that Harmonic drive gears are just strain wave gears (but not all strain wave gears are harmonic drive gears).

Comment: @Foad maybe harmonic drive corp wants the other page to stick around

Comment: well, it is very confusing though. Wikipedia belongs to us, not USM. Does anybody know how we can merge these two pages together?

Comment: I don't see how it's _confusing_.  The wikipedia articles are extremely clear with what they say.  It almost looks as though someone just made the strain wave gear article to draw attention to the fact that Harmonic Drive is a brand, not the actual type of gear (note the SWG page only references the harmonic drive website).

Comment: @Foad Corporations are also allowed to modify wiki articles under the same rules  as everyone else.

Comment: guys, the issue is that the effort is divided between two different pages. not only it is confusing, it is also inefficient.

Comment: @Foad It's not divided; it's repeated.  As far as I can tell the SWG page doesn't have anything unique in it.